# Need manual download latest update of gta v (pc)

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I need to download the update manually because I can’t download it from social club. It gives me every time the same error when 99%

Comment: What's the error message you receive?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a manual download option, as updates to the game are either distributed through Steam, or through the standalone Rockstar Warehouse. According to this [Rockstar Support Article](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/212226788/How-to-Resolve-Issues-Downloading-Patches-for-GTAV-on-PC), if your download keeps failing you should try the following option:

> A good first step to fixing patch download issues for GTAV is to use a new command line argument that was introduced with patch 1.30. This applies only to the standalone, Rockstar Warehouse version as the Steam version patches through Steam.
>
> #### For the standalone, Rockstar Warehouse version:
>
> - Hit "Start", "Run", and type `cmd`. Hit enter.
> - Type `cd c:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V` in the cmd window that pops up. If you installed GTAV in a different directory, be sure to type in that directory instead. Hit enter.
> - Type `GTAVLauncher.exe -verify -noChunkedDownload` in this window and hit enter.
>
> This allows the Social Club launcher to download the patch all at once instead of in chunks, which is known to fix downloading issues for certain connection types.
>
> If this command line parameter doesn’t work for you, please double check that the following ports are open for your PC:
>
> - TCP Ports: 80, 443
> - UDP Ports: 6672, 61455, 61457, 61456, and 61458
>
> GTA Online requires these ports to be open for optimal performance.

Comment: https://www.grandtheftauto5.fr/telechargements/patchs/